# Is it possible for a windows application to access a database in linux

Tags: linux, database, windows

Our application is windows based and database is also in Windows environment. My doubt is can this application access the same database when it is in Linux environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to mention the database port  and ip of the machine where database is installed then it will connect.